# How to get the last modified file date and time in php?

Tags: php

I want to get the report of latest downloaded file time from the download folder through php.
I did that but i am getting the date and time as "Uhub Jira 2019-05-23T14_54_05+0530.csv was last modified on :- January 01 1970 05:30:00.".
Provide me if there is any solution.

I tried fileatime and filemtime but not working.

```
$dir = 'C:\Users\ravi.kumar\Downloads';
    if (is_dir($dir))
    {
        if ($dh = opendir($dir))
        {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)
                {
                    $get_ext = pathinfo($file);
                    if(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)=="csv")
                    {
                        date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
                        $date=date("F d Y H:i:s.", getlastmod($file));
                        echo " $file was last modified on :- ".$date;
                        echo "<br>";
                    }
                }
                 closedir($dh);
        }
    }
```

Instead of this "Uhub Jira 2019-05-23T14_54_05+0530.csv was last modified on :- January 01 1970 05:30:00." i need the result like this "Uhub Jira 2019-05-23T14_54_05+0530.csv was last modified on :- May 23 2019 03:36:00."

Comment: show us the code of `getlastmod($file)` function. this function needs to return `strtotime(modified date)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
 $date=date("F d Y H:i:s.", getlastmod($file));
```

to

```
 $date=date("F d Y H:i:s", strtotime(getlastmod($file)));
```

Comment: after using "echo date('F d, Y, H:i:s', strtotime(getlastmod($file)));" still i am getting 
January 01, 1970, 01:00:00

Answer (score 0):

`getlastmod` is an internal function that does not take any arguments - and it returns the last modification date of the currently executed PHP file.

If you are looking for the last modification data, you should better use `filemtime`